VSCode throws error as if $props variable not accessible in HTML, in Svelte 5 component
With this Component code:
<script>
  let { srcFile } = $props();
</script>

<img src={srcFile}/>

The reference to srcFile in the img tag throws an error as if the variable was never defined.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | null | undefined'.

However, this error just appears in VSCode, not the npm server running vite. Also, images load correctly in-browser. What should I fix about my VSCode config so that it's in touch with reality?
My package.json:
{
    "name": "viewer",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev --host",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^3.0.5",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^4.0.0",
        "@types/eslint": "^9.6.0",
        "eslint": "^9.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.45.1",
        "prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.2.6",
        "svelte": "^5.0.5",
        "svelte-check": "^4.0.0",
        "typescript": "^5.5.0",
        "typescript-eslint": "^8.0.0",
        "vite": "^5.4.4"
    },
    "type": "module"
}



That's just a type error, do you have checkJs enabled in a jsconfig.json/tsconfig.json? Then again, it should be typed any without any annotations, I think...

Is your extension up to date? Is the type of $props being resolved? (Should be function $props(): any — no generic)

I'm using typescript, and in tsconfig.Json contains "checkJS": true.
The type of $props resolved to function $props(): any (specifically, when I hover the mouse over it in VSCode.

I've resolved the situation. Looks like I may have confused the Typescript/Svelte compiler. The project uses Typescript, I had just disabled it in this component while debugging, by removing lang="ts" from the script tag.
Additionally, being explicit with the type with the props destructured return had a syntax different than I had guessed.
This works perfectly:
<script lang="ts">
  let { srcFile }: { srcFile: string } = $props();
</script>

<img src={srcFile} class="contained_photo" alt="alt" />

